# Klipfolio data integration with Highchart Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, klipfolio

I am working on creating a Klipfolio Gantt chart using Highchart. I am able to create the gantt chart using Klipfolio's Html component, but I am having trouble integrating the data.

**Klipfolio HTML Template**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="title_text" style="display:none;">
{{each data}}
${$value.title}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

This pulls the data I need and allows me to add it to the chart script.

**Javascript Code - data**

```
var title = $("#title_text");
```

This code adds the data to the categories.

**Partial Highchart Script**

```
   $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'xrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts X-range study'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: '',
            categories: [$(title).text()],
            min: 0,
            max: 2
        },
```

The results adds ALL the data as one category though.
Example

```
Category 1 []
Category 2 []
Category 3 [data 1, data 2, data 3]
```

How do I pull the data and have it separate into individual categories?

```
Category 1 [data 1]
Category 2 [data 2]
Category 3 [data 3]
```

Comment: What is passed into categories array? Could you post exemplary category data, so a pattern will be visible? `$(title).text()` is a single string that needs to be split into multiple ones - one for each category.

Comment: normally the category array is written `categories: ['data1','data2','data3'],` I am trying to figure out how to split my data into the multiple ones.

Comment: If you will post your data here, then we can help you, but basically you could do something similar e.g to splitting the full string - http://jsfiddle.net/smynu4xe/

Answer (score 1):

Klipfolio actually uses highcharts for our javascript charting library already, so your best bet is to contact support and make a request for Gantt chart type to be added. Adding Libraries through the html component can lead unpredictable results.

That said for your specific issue it looks like the reason you are getting it all in one category is that $("#title_text") is wrapping everything, to solve this you could change your each to look something like this:

```
<div id="title_text" style="display:none;">
{{each data}}
   <div id="${$value.title}">${$value.title}</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

and then you would have a unique id for each one?